# Pycharm code inspection with remote interpreter

Tags: python, pycharm

I am using PyCharm professional edition 2018.1 I am using remote interpreter via ssh. As a result, when I use shortcuts to Inspect Code (e.g. look at the source of a function I am using in the main script), the tab that opens refers to a file on the remote server `/system/remote_resources/.../...`

This is quite annoying because this is not the file I need to modify, since it is just a temporary copy of the local file and it already happened to me to modify the remote file, which has no effect on the execution.

Is there a way for PyCharm code inspection to open the local script, rather than the remote copy?

This is how I configure the ssh connection. No path mappings are set.

[image]

Comment: Can you share how you setup to use remote interpreter via ssh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution that works for me.

```
Settings -> Project -> Project Structure
```

Then right-click on folders and select `Sources`, so they appear on the menu on the right under `Source Folders`.

Now the code inspection opens my local file, not those copied in `/system/remote_resources/`

Answer (score 4):

You need to specify path mappings for particular run configuration or interpreter.
After that your local files will point to the remote ones.
E.g. `/User/local/project= /User/remote/project`

Path mappings for the interpreter:

**Pycharm** > **Preferences** > **Project** > **Project Interpreter** > **Click on Project**

[image]

Path mappings for run configurations:

**Run** > **Edit configuration** > **Choose run cofig** > **Choose remote interperter** > **Fill in mappings**

[image]

Just to be clear it will still cache some files:
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206593675-Path-Mappings-does-not-work-for-me

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you be more explicit about how I need to set the path mapping?

Comment: @FLab local_path <- path of project|files|libs and corresponding path on the remote. Eg.
Local/machine/project_name=/remote/machine/project_name
In the first image you can see the path :)

Answer (score 4):

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-remote-interpreters-via-ssh.html#ssh

Also make sure you refresh the code (set it to automatically upload).

[image]

You can also upload your updated files manually, from Tools->Deployment -> Upload to default server.